# What causes "please check whether the agconnect-services.json file is added to your app project" in using HMS Map Kit with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

I already added the agconnect-services.json file and already succeeded in integrating HMS Push Kit in getting AAID and device token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I added `apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'` in `/android/app/build.gradle` under `apply plugin: "com.android.application"`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this configuration must be added **to the next line of** `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to the app-level **build.gradle** file. Otherwise, an error may occur.

```
apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```